How to get VSCodium to use default file manager
I have installed VSCodium, in Kubuntu.
I use Dolphin as default file explorer/manager in my SO.
Buen when I want to search to open a folder from VSCodium, the app used its File, it seems to be default file manager for Gnome... (?)
How can I change that config, to make VSCodium use Dolphin as file manager?

VSCodium uses zenity for the file dialog which looks like GNOME because it uses GTK and GNOME design elements. Unfortunately I don't think you can use another file dialog. zenity is used in a lot of Linux software because of its ease of implementation.
